# JupyterLab keeps giving a syntax error for else when there are no indentation issues

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run this code but Jupyter keeps giving me the following syntax error at the else condition.

```
  File "<ipython-input-24-beb6bcd9d77b", line 24
    else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was running a similar code earlier and else worked there but I don't understand what's wrong with this code.

```
valid = True

while valid:
    
    if predators != 0 and prey != 0:

        preyCount.append(prey)
        predatorCount.append(predators)

        prey = prey * (1 + preyGrowth - predationRate * predators)
        predators = predators * (1 - predShrink + predFedBirthRate * preyCount[-1]
        
    else:
        
        valid = False
```

Comment: Missing `)` in the line before.

Comment: Rule #2 or #3 for syntax errors: look on the line above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, always look on the line above if you know a line is definitely correct syntax. In this case, `predators = predators * (1 - predShrink + predFedBirthRate * preyCount[-1]` is missing a parenthesis at the end -- it should be `predators = predators * (1 - predShrink + predFedBirthRate * preyCount[-1])`). This causes Python to think that you are trying to do:

```py
predators = predators * (1 - predShrink + predFedBirthRate * preyCount[-1] else
```

which makes no sense.